# Convertir filas a columnas en SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL

```
SELECT Pagos.Tipo_Pago, CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta, sum(importe) AS SumaDeimporte
FROM CuentaBanco INNER JOIN Pagos ON CuentaBanco.CuentaBancoId = Pagos.CuentaBancoId 
GROUP BY Pagos.Tipo_Pago, CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta;
```

### Que me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Tipo_Pago       |NombreCuenta|SumaDeImporte|
-------------------------------------
Anticipo        | Gaby       | $5,500      |
Anticipo        | Javier     |$12,000      |
Anticipo        | Ramon      | $9,000      |
Anticipo Inicial| Gaby       | $1,500      |
Anticipo Inicial| Javier     | $1,500      |
CitaValoracion  | Gaby       |   $250      |
CxC             | Gaby       | $7,000      |
CxC             | Javier     |   $500      |
```

Pero necesito que el resultado se muestre en fila por nombreCuenta y agrupado por tipo de pago como se muestra a continuación

```
------------------------------------------
Tipo_Pago       |Gaby     |Javier   | Ramon
------------------------------------------
Anticipo        | $5,500  |$12,000  |$9,000
Anticipo Inicial| $1,500  | $1,50   |  -
CitaValoracion  | $7,000  |   $500  |  -
CxC             | $  250  |   -     |  -
```

El código de la consulta que estoy tratando de realizar es el siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT Pagos.Tipo_Pago, CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta, Sum(Pagos.importe) AS SumaDeimporte
FROM CuentaBanco INNER JOIN Pagos ON CuentaBanco.CuentaBancoId = Pagos.CuentaBancoId
GROUP BY Pagos.Tipo_Pago, CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta
    
)  PIVOT(
SUM(importe)
 FOR (NombreCuenta) IN([Gaby],[Ramon],[Javier], AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El escenario que planteas:

```
Create table CuentaBanco (CuentaBancoId int, NombreCuenta varchar(100))
Create table Pagos(CuentaBancoId int, Tipo_Pago varchar(100),importe int)
```

Insertamos valores:

```
Insert into CuentaBanco (CuentaBancoId, NombreCuenta)
values
(1,'Gaby'),
(2,'Javier'),
(3,'Ramon');
Insert into Pagos(CuentaBancoId, Tipo_Pago, importe)
values
(1,'Anticipo',2000),
(1,'Anticipo',3500),
(2,'Anticipo',3000),
(2,'Anticipo',9000),
(3,'Anticipo',9000),
(1,'Anticipo Inicial',1500),
(2,'Anticipo Inicial',1000),
(2,'Anticipo Inicial',500),
(1,'CitaValoracion',250),
(1,'CxC',7000),
(2,'CxC',500);
```

El pivot.

```
Select * from (
SELECT Pagos.Tipo_Pago
     , CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta
     , Sum(importe) AS SumaDeimporte
       FROM CuentaBanco
            INNER JOIN Pagos ON CuentaBanco.CuentaBancoId = Pagos.CuentaBancoId
       GROUP BY Pagos.Tipo_Pago
              , CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta
) as source
pivot (sum(SumaDeimporte) For NombreCuenta IN ([Gaby],[Javier],[Ramon]))pvt
```

[image: Resultado]

Lo único diferente a tu query, es aplicar un alias al resultado de `pivot`

Si necesitas formatear la salida, para que no devuelva nulos y devuelva guiones, o que el número sea formato moneda, puedes trabajarlo en el `Select *`, variando el asterisco, por el alias de la tabla pivot.

Por ejemplo en Sql Server (no indicas el motor), puedes utilizar la función format.

```
Select pvt.Tipo_Pago
    , FORMAT(pvt.[Gaby],'C', 'en-us') as [Gaby] 
    , FORMAT(pvt.[Javier],'C', 'en-us') as [Javier] 
    , FORMAT(pvt.[Ramon],'C', 'en-us') as [Ramon] 

from (
SELECT Pagos.Tipo_Pago
     , CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta
     , Sum(importe) AS SumaDeimporte
       FROM CuentaBanco
            INNER JOIN Pagos ON CuentaBanco.CuentaBancoId = Pagos.CuentaBancoId
       GROUP BY Pagos.Tipo_Pago
              , CuentaBanco.NombreCuenta
) as source
pivot (sum(SumaDeimporte) For NombreCuenta IN ([Gaby],[Javier],[Ramon]))pvt
```

[image: Resultado 2]

Comment: Como dato adicional, es recomendable no usar la función FORMAT puesto que hace las consultas mucho más lentas (se han medido hasta 40 veces más lentas). Lo ideal es que se deje el formato de números y fechas para la capa de visualización (front-end).

Answer (score 0):

Como una versión alternativa al uso de `PIVOT`, se pueden utilizar funciones de agregado condicionales que tienen una sintaxis sencilla que permite aplicarla con solo copiar/pegar/modificar. También tiene mucha más versatilidad y llega a tener mejor rendimiento si se llegan a necesitar más de un `PIVOT` en la consulta.

```
SELECT p.Tipo_Pago, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cb.NombreCuenta = 'Gaby'   THEN p.importe END) AS Gaby, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cb.NombreCuenta = 'Javier' THEN p.importe END) AS Javier, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cb.NombreCuenta = 'Ramon'  THEN p.importe END) AS Ramon
FROM   CuentaBanco cb
INNER JOIN Pagos p ON cb.CuentaBancoId = p.CuentaBancoId
GROUP BY p.Tipo_Pago;
```